# matplotlib polar streamplot vs quiver

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot streamline then I see wrong result.
I check streamline with quiver then I get right result.
I use same data for both. Why plots is so different?

```
fig = plt.figure()
axs = plt.axes(polar=True)
axs.set_theta_zero_location("N")
axs.set_theta_direction(-1)
YL, ZL = zip(*list(zip(YLr,ZLr))/np.linalg.norm(list(zip(YLr,ZLr)),axis=1, keepdims=True))
YLi = scipy.interpolate.griddata(((np.radians(a_izogn), izogn)),YL,(a_izogn_rad_i[None,:], izogn_i[:,None]),method='cubic')
ZLi = scipy.interpolate.griddata(((np.radians(a_izogn), izogn)),ZL,(a_izogn_rad_i[None,:], izogn_i[:,None]),method='cubic')
r = izogn_i
phi = a_izogn_rad_i
r, phi = np.meshgrid(r, phi)
axs.streamplot(phi.transpose(), r.transpose(),ZLi, YLi, color='red',density=1, linewidth=0.5)
axs.quiver(phi.transpose(), r.transpose(), ZLi, YLi,units='xy',scale=10., zorder=3, color='blue',width=0.007, headwidth=3., headlength=4.)
axs.set_ylim([min(izogn_i), max(izogn_i)])
fig.show();
```

[image: Sample plot]

my data:
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/HzJX/YFc1cLGGR

Answer (score 0):

solved. just plot contour in polar, streamline in cartesian

Answer (score 0):

plot contour in polar, streamline in cartesian.
in result you can see:

[image]